# the biggest common divisor of 2 numbers using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

How could I find the biggest common divisor of 2 numbers using array? I tried to solve it using 2 arrays and I couldn't finish it. How could I improve this program?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   unsigned int A[2][10], B[2][10], a, b, c_exp, d, i1, P, x;
   bool apartine = false;

   cout << "a="; cin >> a;
   cout << "b="; cin >> b;
   P = 1;
   c_exp = 0;
   i1 = 0;
   while (a % 2 == 0)
   {
      c_exp++;
      a = a/2;
   }
   if (c_exp != 0)
   {
      A[i1][0] = 2;
      A[i1][1] = c_exp;
      i1++;
   }
   d = 3;
   while (a != 1 && d <= a)
   {
      c_exp=0;
      while (a % d == 0)
      {
         c_exp++;
         a = a/d;
      }
      if (c_exp!=0)
      {
         A[i1][0] = d;
         A[i1][1] = c_exp;
         i1++;
      }
      d = d+2;
   }
   cout << "\nMatricea A contine:";
   for (int i = 0; i < i1; i++)
   {
      cout << "\n";
      for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
      cout << A[i][j] << ",";
   }
   c_exp = 0;
   i1 = 0;
   while (b % 2 == 0)
   {
      c_exp++;
      b = b/2;
   }
   if (c_exp != 0)
   {
      B[i1][0] = 2;
      B[i1][1] = c_exp;
      i1++;
   }
   d = 3;
   while (b != 1 && d <= b)
   {
      c_exp = 0;
      while (b % d == 0)
      {
         c_exp++;
         b = b/d;
      }
      if (c_exp != 0)
      {
         B[i1][0] = d;
         B[i1][1] = c_exp;
         i1++;
      }
      d = d+2;
   }
   cout << "\nMatricea B contine:";
   for (int i = 0; i < i1; i++)
   {
      cout << "\n";
      for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
         cout << B[i][j] << ",";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

From now on I have to find if the first number of first array exist in the second array and after this I have to compare the exponents of the same number of both array and the lowest one I have to add it to product. After this I have to repeat the same proccess with the second number to the last one of the first array. The problem is that I don't know how to write this.I have to mention that this program isn't complete.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can improve readability **a lot** first by using spaces and new lines appropriately before others would read your post

Comment: You could also improve it with comments that describe what it should do and unit tests that make sure that it does this. Of course, that's *after* splitting it into separate functions.

Comment: Why do you need to use array to find gcd? You can just use `__gcd(a,b)`

Comment: because my teacher told me to solve it with arrays...

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve with your code. It looks over complicated. If I were to find the biggest common divisor of two numbers I would do something like the following:

```
## This is not a correct implementation in C++ (but close to it) ##

Read the two integers **a** and **b**

int max_div(int a, int b){
    int div = a > b ? a : b;
    while (div != 1 && (a%div != 0 && b%div != 0)){
        div--;
    }
    return div;
}
```

This function starts with the minimum of a and b as the highest possible common divisor and then works its way backwards until one of two possible outcomes:

1. It finds a common divisor (a%div == 0 and b%div == 0)
2. It reaches one (always a common divisor)

**EDIT :** Now returns one if no higher divisor is found. (Was returning zero which made no sense)

Answer (score 0):

If you need better solution then you can avoid array and use the below logic.

```
int main()
{
    int a =12 ,b = 20;
    int min = a>b ? a:b; // finding minimum
    if(min > 1)
    {
        for (int i=min/2; i>1; i--)//Reverse loop from min/2 to 1
        {
            if(a%i==0 && b%i==0)
            {
                cout<<i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(min == 1)          
    {
        cout<<"GCD is 1";
    }
    else
        cout<<"NO GCD";

    return 0;
}
```

You can also check the working example [Greatest Common Divisor](http://ideone.com/ANR26b)

Comment: i know how to solve it simpler than with array but i have to solve it using 2 arrays